# Prestashop backend and frontend module display error on some pages

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

On PrestaShop 1.6 on some pages of front end I'm getting the below error and all pages of admin when I'm trying to login I'm getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Invalid compiled template for
>   '/modules/blockbestsellers/views/templates/hook/tab.tpl' <-- thrown in
>   /tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 182

Comment: Try to clear cache deleting the content except `index.php` of this folders `rootofps/cache/smarty/compile` and `rootofps/cache/smarty/cache`, be carefull, not the folders but the content. By the way, it's the 'blockbestsellers' that have a problem.

Comment: Thanks...it works

Comment: You're welcome ;) - I'll put the comment like an answer, if you want to help other people flag as answered ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clear cache deleting the content except index.php of this folders `rootofps/cache/smarty/compile` and `rootofps/cache/smarty/cache`, be carefull, not the folders but the content. By the way, it's the 'blockbestsellers' that have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In first step check storage space, next enable in backend-> Advanced Parameters -> Performance -> Template compilation * Force compilation.

If this not help try remove and install again this module (Bo. Maybe you remove too much code in this file).